# Modulo simple question

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume we have $$ r,k\in\left\{ 0,1,...,n-1\right\}  $$

Do we know that there exists $ m\in\mathbb{N} $ such that $ mk\equiv r\pmod n$?

Comment: No, this we don't know. Pick $m=4, k=2, r=1$.

Comment: I believe @SeverinSchraven means $n=4$

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrr_QJbxoHQ

Comment: If $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime

Comment: @Ivan Yes, thanks for catching the typo!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven So the following $ \left\{ e^{ir\cdot\frac{2\pi}{n}}:r=0,1,...,n-1\right\} \subseteq\left\{ e^{imk\cdot\frac{2\pi}{n}}:m\in\mathbb{N}\right\}  $ does not hold ? where $k$ is a constant satisfies $ k\in\left\{ 0,1,...,n-1\right\}  $

Comment: This holds o,ly if $k$ and $n$ are coprime.

Comment: @Bernard how can I prove it is true if they are coprime? for example if k=n-1

Comment: Using *Bézout's identity* shows $k$ is a unit in the quotient ring $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$; hence any number in $\{0,1, \dots,n-1\}$ is (congruent to) a multiple of $k$.